# How to insert into temp table when looping through a string - Oracle - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt_temptable(
    RowNums   NUMBER(3,0),
    procNums  NUMBER(18,0)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

  inputString  VARCHAR2 ;

  inputString := '12,13,14,15'


SELECT   REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) ProcNums
FROM dual CONNECT BY  REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

  INSERT INTO tt_temptable( 
    SELECT identity(3) RowNums,procNums
      FROM 

);
```

Want to insert 12 , 13, 14 , 15 and identity of 3 length in the temptable so total 4 rows in temptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Oracle 12c`, then you may define an `IDENTITY` column through `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` in your table definition and follow the way below :

```
SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt_temptable(
  2        RowNums NUMBER(3,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  3        procNums  NUMBER(18,0)
  4    ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

Table created

SQL> 
SQL> DECLARE
  2    inputString  VARCHAR2(50) := '12,13,14,15';
  3  BEGIN
  4      INSERT INTO tt_temptable(procNums)
  5         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) ProcNums
  6           FROM dual
  7        CONNECT BY  REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> SELECT * FROM tt_temptable;

ROWNUMS            PROCNUMS
------- -------------------
      1                  12
      2                  13
      3                  14
      4                  15
```

To reset the `IDENTITY` column (`RowNums`), use :

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE tt_temptable MODIFY( RowNums Generated as Identity (START WITH 1));
```

*whenever the shared locks on the table are released.*

Comment: any idea how to reset the identties of this temp table

Answer (score 1):

```
insert 
  into tt_temptable 
select NVL((select max(a.rownums) 
                from tt_temptable a
              ),100)+rownum
         ,procNums 
  from (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('10,20,30','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) ProcNums,level as lvl
          FROM dual 
       CONNECT BY  REGEXP_SUBSTR ('10,20,30','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
       )x
```

Comment: thanks a lot , any idea how to reset the identities on temp table