# How to insert row numbers while inserting temp table in column - oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable(
    rowseq     NUMBER,
    types NUMBER(18,0)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;


INSERT INTO tempTable( types ) SELECT
        regexp_substr( inputString , '[^,]+',  1, level ) inputs
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        regexp_substr( inputString, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

using the above insert into query , suppose the

```
 inputString = '10','30','40'
```

I am creating temp table like

```
rowSeq  types
null      10
null      30 
null      40
```

What edit should be done in insert query , so that table can belike this

```
rowSeq  types
1        10
2        30
3        40
```

Comment: Simply `SELECT LEVEL, REGEXP_SUBSTR(inputString, '[^,]+',  1, LEVEL ) inputs ...`

Comment: Isn't this mostly a similar requirement as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264509/how-to-insert-into-temp-table-when-looping-through-a-string-oracle-pl-sql ? , Barbaros suggested you to use `IDENTITY` column, right?